# Insert Statement Problem

Tags: php, mysql

```
$lastname = clean($_SESSION['lastname']);
$firstname = clean($_SESSION['firstname']);
$mi = clean($_SESSION['mi']);
$nickname = clean($_SESSION['nickname']);
$studentno = clean ($_SESSION['studentno']);
$password = clean ($_SESSION['password']);
$cpassword = clean ($_SESSION['cpassword']);
$bdate = clean($_POST['bdate']);
$maddress = clean($_POST['maddress']);
$paddress = clean($_POST['paddress']);
$status = clean($_POST['status']);
$religion = clean($_POST['religion']);
$telno = clean($_POST['telno']);
$celno = clean($_POST['celno']);
$email = clean($_POST['email']);
$nationality = clean($_POST['nationality']);
$batch = clean($_POST['batch']);
$dept = clean($_POST['dept']);
$course = clean($_POST['course']);
$achvmnts = clean($_POST['achvmnts']);
$emp = clean($_POST['emp']);
$empadd = clean($_POST['empadd']);
$position = clean($_POST['position']);
$emptelno = clean($_POST['emptelno']);
$empemail = clean($_POST['empemail']);
```

I have the following INSERT query for the values above where the first 7 are being retrieved from a saved session, everything are declared as varchar except for the fields bdate = date, celno and studentno = bigint, :

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$dept`(lastname,firstname, mi,nickname,bdate,maddress,paddress,status,religion,telno,celno,email,nationality,password,studentno,batch,dept,course,achvmnts,emp,empadd,position) VALUES
('$lastname','$firstname','$mi','$nickname','$bdate', '$maddress','$paddress','$status,','$religion','$telno',$celno,'$email','$nationality','$password',$studentno,'$batch', '$dept','$course','$achvmnts','$emp','$empadd,'$position')");
```

.I can't seem to find the error in this query, for hours i have been receiving "Query Error". can anyone please help me find the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: assign the query sting to a var so you can echo it out.

Comment: Note there is a comma in `'$status,'` - that can't be causing an error, but might be a mistake anyway. Is it really intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in your insert right there:

```
'$empadd, '$position')");
```

the 2. quotation is missing

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$dept`(lastname,firstname, mi,nickname,bdate,maddress,paddress,status,religion,telno,celno,email,nationality,password,studentno,batch,dept,course,achvmnts,emp,empadd,position) VALUES
('$lastname','$firstname','$mi','$nickname','$bdate', '$maddress','$paddress','$status','$religion','$telno',$celno,'$email','$nationality','$password',$studentno,'$batch', '$dept','$course','$achvmnts','$emp','$empadd','$position')");
```

Should work if thats the problem.

(Edit: removed the , in '$status,' since someone mentioned it in the comments

Comment: I moved my comment to the question (it belongs there more). The comma might be intended though.

Comment: Ye I recognized that, it still seems strange though and I believe it's a mistake

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need the quotations on the INSERT INTO '$dept'. Also, I think your quotations are different, and $studentno has no quotations, I'm not sure if that was intentional. Last, could you post the exact query error

Comment: They're not quotations around `$dept`, they're backticks. They tell mysql that `$dept` identifies a table (or database, index, column etc). Strictly, all the column names in the query *should* be marked with backticks too.

Comment: @adam no, not should. Must, but only if they collide with a reserved name (e.g. "user"). Otherwise, please leave them out. They're a portability problem and an eyesore.

Comment: (and multiple columns/tables distinguished by Varying Case, but that's an awful practise)

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, this is a ridiculously huge INSERT to be making. Here are things I noted

1. `'$status,',` looks incorrect. This would add the status with a trialing comma
2. `'$empadd,` is missing a trailing quote
3. `$celno` is not placed within quotations. This is risky. All phone numbers should be stored as VARCHAR fields.
4. Consider using `sprintf` with `mysql_real_escape_string` in order to ensure that your variables are formatted correctly. For more information, consult the PHP manual docs on [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 0):

The code could be a bit more readable and less open to errors resulting from repetition:

```
$session_columns = array('lastname','firstname','mi','nickname','studentno',
  'password','cpassword');
$post_columns = array('bdate','maddress','paddress','status','religion','telno',
  'celno','email','nationality','batch','dept','course','achvmnts','emp',
  'empadd','position','emptelno','empemail');

$assignments = array();
foreach ($session_columns as $column)
  $assignments[] = sprintf("$column = '%s'", clean($_SESSION[$column]));
foreach ($post_columns as $column)
  $assignments[] = sprintf("$column = '%s'", clean($_POST[$column]));

$sql = "INSERT INTO `$dept` SET ".implode(', ', $assignments);
```